# How do I make the jQuery table sorter always initially sort on the last column?

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I'm using the JQuery tablesorter v 2.0.  I currently have it set up like so

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({
    sortList: [[4,0]]
});
```

but how would I set up the default sort order to always be the last column in the table?  The reason hard-coding a number may not be ideal is because I'm dynamically generating the table data and sometime the table will have five columns and sometime it will have six.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count the number of headers in your table and use that to get the last column index. For example:

```
// Get the number of "th" within the first "tr":
var columnCount = $('table tr:first').children('th').length;

$("#myTable").tablesorter({
    sortList: [[columnCount - 1, 0]]
});
```

Comment: This is the ideal answer... another possibility that will work, but only if you have a small table, is to add `$('table thead th:last').click();` after the initialization code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/1823/)).

Answer (score 1):

You can write a jQuery plugin that counts the number of table headers for a given table (accounting for column span as well).

The sample data below is from the *Getting Started* section from the [docs](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.colCount = function() {
    var colCount = 0;
    this.find('tr:first-child td').each(function () {
      colCount += $(this).attr('colspan') ? +$(this).attr('colspan') : 1;
    });
    return colCount;
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable').tablesorter({
    sortList: [
      [$('#myTable').colCount() - 1, 0]
    ],
    theme : 'dropbox'
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.28.5/css/theme.dropbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.28.5/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.28.5/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Due</th>
      <th>Web Site</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bach</td>
      <td>Frank</td>
      <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.frank.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>Jason</td>
      <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td>
      <td>$100.00</td>
      <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Conway</td>
      <td>Tim</td>
      <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.timconway.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```